# drop rows after sum condition reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to drop rows from my data frame after I hit some value.

example data set:

```
num value 
1   2000
2   3000
3   2000

x = 5000 # my limiter
y = 0 # my bucket for values

# I want to do something like...
for row in df:
    if y <= x:
        y =+ df["Values"]
    elif y > x:
        df.drop(row)
        continue
```

The elif might not make sense but it expresses the idea, it is the parsing I am more concerned with. I cant seem to use df["Values"] in my embedded if statement.

I get the error:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
```

which is odd because i can run this line by itself outside of the if statement.

Comment: What is `df`?­­

Comment: This code wouldn't  produce your error message, because the line `y =+ df["Values"]` contains two mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
x = 5000
df = df[df['value'].cumsum() <= x]
print (df)
   num  value
0    1   2000
1    2   3000
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['value'].cumsum())
0    2000
1    5000
2    7000
Name: value, dtype: int64

print (df['value'].cumsum() <= x)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error message, because you assign the whole column to your variable `y`. Instead you want to assign only the value from column `value` and add it to your variable.

```
#print(df)
#num value 
#1   2000
#2   3000
#3   2000
#4   4000
#5   1000

x = 5000 
y = 0 

#iterate over rows
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if y < x:
        #add the value to y
        y += row["value"]
    elif y >= x:
        #drop rest of the dataframe
        df = df.drop(df.index[index:])
        break

#output from print(df)
#   num  value
#0    1   2000
#1    2   3000
```

But it would be faster, if you just used pandas builtin `cumsum` function. ([see jezrael's answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48850687/8881141))